# Why hyperconjugation is called as σ to π* donation for alkenes and alkynes?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, hyperconjugation

Why hyperconjugation is called as σ to π* donation for alkenes and alkynes if for C2 lowest unoccupied molecular orbital is σ2p not π*2p?